# How to build a conditional query in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The following code works with **no** querystrings or **one** querystring only. In other words, simply going to `/characters` returns all characters. But if you were to specify a querystring parameter `/characters?gender=male` it will return only male characters.

How could I extend this to work with either **1**, **2**, **3**, or **no** querystrings? ***I would really prefer to avoid writing 8 or 9 different if-statements for each case***. I was hoping Mongoose would simply ignore a **$where** clause if it's `null` or `undefined`, but that is not the case (see commented out code).

```
  var gender = req.query.gender;
  var race = req.query.race;
  var bloodline = req.query.bloodline;

  var query = Character.find();

  if (gender)
    query = query.where('gender').equals(gender);
  if (race)
    query = query.where('race').equals(race);
  if (bloodline)
    query = query.where('bloodline').equals(bloodline);

  /*
  query
    .where('gender').equals(new RegExp('^' + gender + '$', 'i'))
    .where('race').equals(new RegExp('^' + race + '$', 'i'))
    .where('bloodline').equals(new RegExp('^' + bloodline + '$', 'i'));
  */

  query.exec(function(err, characters) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(characters);
  });
```

**Edit:**
Well I guess I could do it with 7 if-statements for now. Unless someone finds a more elegant solution.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks guys. It's difficult to pick one answer because both of you have helped me to achieve this concise solution. Here is the entire thing now.

```
var conditions = {};

for (var key in req.query) {
  if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    conditions[key] = new RegExp('^' + req.query[key] + '$', 'i');
  }
}

var query = Character.find(conditions);
query.exec(function(err, characters) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send({ characters: characters });
});
```

Comment: No problem, but you should pick an answer for future users to know which helped you more. If you can't, think about writing your own answer and checking that one as correct.

Comment: You should remove your Edit 2 and write your own answer, that is great btw

Comment: Very nice - works great; except for the sanitation part with the RegEx which produces odd queries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to call `Query#where` repeatedly, since you can pass all the conditions to [Mongoose Model#find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) as:

```
var filteredQuery = {},
  acceptableFields = ['gender', 'race', /* etc */ ];

acceptableFields.forEach(function(field) {
  req.query[field] && filteredQuery[field] = req.query[field];
});

var query = Character.find(filteredQuery);
```

You'll also want to sanitize `req.query` depending on the allowed parameters you have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I am using destructing of objects for this task.

```
const filter = req.query.filter ? { _id: { $in: req.query.filter.split(',') } } : {};
const category = req.query.category ? { category: req.query.category } : {};
// more variables that you need and are empty objects if don't exist

const all = await Post.find({ ...filter, ...category }).exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,

I would recommend something like this:

```
var query = Character.find()
if(req.params.length < 0) {
  for(var key in req.params) {
    query.where(req.params[key]).equals(key);
  }
} else {
  // do something without query params
}
```

this is not tested by me but it should work (maybe you need to modify it a bit but you get the idea). This solution is all about not checking what actually is in the params so be sure only good stuff comes in or validate it somewhere in the for loop, but would require some regex or if statements.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: **To future visitors**: Accepted answer's example does not work. I am not even using req.params, but rather req.query. Instead of chaining `.where`, I am building a *condition* object dynamically and then pass it to `Character.find()`. Refer to my Edit #2.