# Conditional query in Mongoose with integers in query

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am looking at this question [How to build a conditional query in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693029/how-to-build-a-conditional-query-in-mongoose/) And trying to build on it by handling integers in the query string.

I have the below code.

```
    var conditions = {};
    var patt = new RegExp('^[0-9]');

    for (var key in req.query) {
      if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(patt.test(req.query[key])) {
            conditions[key] = new RegExp('^' + parseInt(req.query[key]) + '$', 'i');
        }
        else {
            conditions[key] = new RegExp('^' + req.query[key] + '$', 'i');
        }
      }
    }
```

When I do `&color=red` this returns colors that equal red.

But when I do `&version=2` etc I get nothing returned.

I have put a console log in my if statement to confirm that the `patt` regex is picking up the value starting with an `int` but this does seem to execute as I would expect (returning results where version = 2).

If I was to restructure my code as below, this does partialy work.  However this solution isn't really maintainable as I would need to add a condition for each potential param and need to go back and modify as more become available.

```
var version = parseInt(req.query.version);
var query = Model.find();
if (version) {
    query = query.where('version').equals(version);
}
```

Another issue with the above snippet is if I am looking for a string eg title and title starts with a number eg 7up, then this returns no results either.

```
var title= req.query.title;
var query = Model.find();
if (version) {
    query = query.where('title').equals(title);
}
```

Is there a solution I can use here that will allow me to use any param in the request and treat as an integer if it matches my `patt` regex?

Below is a snippet of my data model, once I can get this working I intend to add more items that are either `numbers` or `strings`

```
    var ModelSchema = new Schema({
        version: {
            type: Number,
            trim: true
        },
        color: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },    
    });

    mongoose.model('Model', ModelSchema);
```

Comment: Could you please show us your mongoose model.

Comment: @NarendraSoni I have updated the question, your question has got me to do some more testing at my end and I have found another issue as well if a string starts with an int eg 7up. do you have any ideas?

Comment: If I follow your code it looks like you're trying to use a regular expression to search integers in your query, which doesn't make sense to me. You have `conditions[key] = new RegExp('^' + parseInt(req.query[key]) + '$', 'i');` but you should be able to simply have `conditions[key] = parseInt(req.query[key]);`

Comment: @BrianShamblen you should put this in an answer so I can accept it as it appears to work thanks,  I would also be interested if you had any thoughts on if it was possible to handle a string starting with a number?

Comment: If you change your regex exp to '^[0-9]$' that should match only strings that contain numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your code it looks like you're trying to use a regular expression to search integers in your query, which doesn't make sense to me. You have `conditions[key] = new RegExp('^' + parseInt(req.query[key]) + '$', 'i');` but you should be able to simply have `conditions[key] = parseInt(req.query[key]);`

Glad that worked. Thanks!