# Conditional query in Mongoose where params may be missing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to pass through values for a search using Mongoose. This doesn't work... I don't think...
[How to build a conditional query in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693029/how-to-build-a-conditional-query-in-mongoose)
As I will want to apply logic to the value, for example with dates I will pass through two values and do greater than and less than. This is purely an = query.

Comment: hey, please show us the code you have tried, the errors that you get. We'd love to help out but need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.gt` and `.lt` for greater than and less than respectively.

```
var query = Character.find();

if (maxDate)
    query = query.where('dateParam').lt(maxDate);
if (minDate)
    query = query.where('dateParam').gt(minDate);

query.exec(function(err, characters) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(characters);
});
```

Comment: As a follow up. I want to allow for searches that do not have text. This doesn't work, any suggestions?

    if(req.query.text){
        var query = Record.find(
                { $text : { $search : req.query.text } },
                { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
        )
    } else {
        var query = Record.find()
    }

(sorry, I cannot get code formatting to work...)

Comment: @latitudehopper Can you please post a different question for this ?